# How to select row in datatable (jquery datatables)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using below **code 1** to populate my datatable. However, when I tried to access my datatable using **code 2**, I dont get this response: *alert( customerTable.row( this ).data() );*

What am I doing wrong here?

**Code 1**

```
$(searchClientBtn).on("click", function () {
 
            var clientLastName = $(clientLastNameTxt).val();
            var clientFirstName = $(clientFirstNameTxt).val();
            var clientMiddleName = $(clientMiddleNameTxt).val();
            var clientDateOfBirth = $(clientDateOfBirthTxt).val();
 
            if ( clientLastName.length == 0 && clientFirstName.length == 0 && clientMiddleName.length == 0 ) {
                alert("Please enter search parameter/s to proceed.");
            }
            else {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("firstName", $("#clientFirstNameTxt").val());
                formData.append("middleName", $("#clientMiddleNameTxt").val());
                formData.append("lastName", $("#clientLastNameTxt").val());
                formData.append("dateOfBirth", $("#clientDateOfBirthTxt").val());
 
                //console.log(formData);
                var booking = new booking();
 
                booking.getListCustomer(formData, {
                    onSuccess: function (xdata) {
 
                       var customerTable = $("#customerTable").DataTable({
                           data: xdata.result,
                           processing: true,
                        columns: [
 
                            { 'data': 'FirstName' },
                            { 'data': 'MiddleName' },
                            { 'data': 'LastName' },
                            { 'data': 'Birthdate' }
                           ]
 
                    });
                    },
                    onError: function (xdata) {
                        alert("An error occured");
                    }
                });
 
 
                $(clientSearchModal).modal("show");
 
            }
        });
```

**Code 2**

```
$("#customerTable").on("click", "tbody tr", function () {
           alert("imclicked");
            alert( customerTable.row( this ).data() );
 
        });
```

Comment: What *do* you get?  Likely to be an error in the console `customerTable is not defined` - in your `success:` you have `var customerTable = ` - this has limited scope (which can slightly confusing for js with `var`) - but it won't be accessible in your 2nd click event handler.  What errors do you have in the console?

Comment: hi, i'm getting customerTable.row is not function in the console. @freedomn-m I'm trying to figure out how to access my table on my 2nd click event handler

Answer (score 0):

Need to define variable.

```
$("#customerTable").on("click", "tbody tr", function () {
           var customerTable = $('#customerTable').DataTable(); //Here need to define variable
           alert("imclicked");
           alert( customerTable.row( this ).data() );
 
   });
```

Comment: hi, thanks for this! However, i'm getting undefined when I do this